# How to convert lambda expression to object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo grid  and the columns binding is like below:

```
columns.Bound(c=>c.Description).Title(Global.Description).Width(600);
```

Description is from database table and it contain string with html tags like br tags 
but when it print the text it print the br tag also and hence i cannot get line break.

So the possibility is using html.raw but as it accepts object as argument and issue lies how to convert this lambda expression to object so that i can use it in kendo grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer,
encoded(false) will set the thing right and it worked.
    columns.Bound(c=>c.Description).Title(Global.Description).Width(600).Encoded(false);

Answer (score 0):

hmmm... lambdas aren't objects... but delegate

```
var o = new Action(() => { });
```

Comment: can u tell me how to write in the context of  above because it is telling delegate cannot take 1 argument